# RStudio cannot find the path specified when opening up a script

Tags: r, rstudio, filepath

I have Windows 11, R version 4.2.1, RStudio version 2022.02.3 Build 492, although this problem existed with R 4.1.2 and and older version of RStudio as well, I updated in an attempt to fix it.

For one particular RStudio project (all other project have no problems), I can't open any scripts, and when I try, I get the error "The system cannot find the path specified". While the path is long, it is shorter than the windows file path character limit of 260 characters (it's 230).

[This previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70184115/rstudio-cannot-save-files-or-open-rscripts-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-sp) seems similar but is a) more widespread and b) my issue is not fixed by running as administrator.

Additionally, the proposed solution does not seem to apply as my machine does not have a `HOME` variably in the system variables as described.

There are some other questions with the phrase "the system cannot find the path specified" but none of them seem directly applicable.

Additionally, I can open the script just fine in R or in notepad. It only fails to open in RStudio.

Comment: What happens if you use `getwd()`. It would show you the current working directory. Can you set the working directory by using `setwd()`?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. setwd() and getwe() work fine. I can run scripts, I just can't save them in a directory that I know exists. It seems more like an RStudio issue than an R issue.